# Compare string datatype to a date datatype PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

In my MySQL database, I have this Time data type as one of my values: **06:00:00**. I have the following query that checks the time as one of the conditions that has to be satisfied

```
$time = "06:00:00";

$getdetails=SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, EMAIL 
FROM parents 
WHERE Email_Receive_Time = $time; 

$results=mysql_query($getdetails);
```

However I do not get any results. On further research I have seen that it is because I am comparing a STRING type value ($time) to a TIME type value (value in my database). Is there a way i can compare the two without changing my database structure to a varchar? All help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is neither SQL nor PHP. Posting dummy code is quite pointless in general. Post your *real* code and you'll be able to get advice on your *real* problem.

Comment: No need to post long php mysql statements to busy stackoverflow users. Clearly I got my point through with this dummy code since I have more than 1 answer.

Comment: you cannot be more wrong. You can notice that most of answers were wrong. You it's you to blame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL is perfectly capable of comparing a string to a TIME value. You just need to have the proper query syntax. In your case, you need to quote the comparison value:

```
$time = "06:00:00";

$getdetails = "SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, EMAIL 
FROM parents 
WHERE Email_Receive_Time = '$time'"; 

$results=mysql_query($getdetails);
```

And if it is user-supplied, well you should escape it.

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong.
Your mistake is much simpler, it has nothing to do with data formats, but with query format.

Ask yourself what does mean 06:00:00 in terms of SQL syntax.

Btw, running query this way will help you **A LOT**:

$results=mysql_query($getdetails) **or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$getdetails);**

always run all your queries this way and get in touch with every error occurred

Comment: Thanks for not spoon feeding me the answer

Answer (score 1):

This will work when comparing against TIME type of field:

To compare against DATETIME or TIMESTAMP, I'd suggest running the $time variable through strotime() first.

```
$time = "06:00:00";

$getdetails = "SELECT First_Name, 
                      Last_Name, 
                      EMAIL 
               FROM   parents 
               WHERE  Email_Receive_Time = '$time'"; 

$results = mysql_query($getdetails);
```

Comment: I didn't downvote the answer but `strtotime("06:00:00")` is `'1297314000'`. It won't compare with `'06:00:00'` as expected.

Comment: I was expecting your database stored time values to be MySQLs default DATETIME or TIMESTAMP, comparing a Unix Timestamp against either works fine. Just a moment, checking how it goes with TIME, sorry for misreading.

Comment: Tested and verified, having a TIME field with value of 06:00:00 I was able to get it shown with SELECT * FROM test WHERE time = "06:00:00". I updated original post.

Comment: you'd better delete it, as it's become weak copy of netcoder's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using STR_TO_DATE function, it should work for you.

Thanks
Ravi Mudaliar

Comment: Yes I also tried str_to_date. I did STR_TO_DATE('$time','%h:%m:%s') and it worked. But I have to admit netcoder's way is by far the best.